# Screenshot with CCClippingNode - cocos2d-iphone-2.1-beta4

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, screenshot

I'm testing the new clipping node added in Cocos2d 2.1 beta4 `CCClippingNode`. However, I'm unable to take a screenshot the clipped node using the method below. The end result is the unclipped image. You can find the new build here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download

```
+ (UIImage *) screenshotNode:(CCNode*)startNode {
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    CCRenderTexture * rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width height:winSize.height];

    [rtx begin];
    [startNode visit];
    [rtx end];

    return [rtx getUIImage];
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that clipping doesn't work with the render texture. If you can verify this in a simple test case you should report it as a bug.

Answer (score 4):

**Suggested Solution**

The following code seems to work with Cocos2d v2.1:

```c
+ (UIImage *) screenshotNode:(CCNode*)startNode {
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    CCRenderTexture * rtx =
        [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width
                                         height:winSize.height
                                    pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888
                             depthStencilFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8];

    [rtx beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0 depth:1.0f];
    [startNode visit];
    [rtx end];

    return [rtx getUIImage];
}
```

**Explanation**

The following two changes were necessary to make the original code work:

1. Specify the `depthStencilFormat` parameter when creating the `CCRenderTexture` object. By default, `CCRenderTexture` does not create a depth/stencil buffer.

   - The `depthStencilFormat` parameter *must* be set to `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` in order to create a stencil buffer, at least in v2.1. The `CCRenderTexture` initialization code checks specifically for this value.
2. Call `beginWithClear` using a depth value of `1.0f` instead of `begin`.

   - It appears that just calling `begin` never clears the depth buffer. Inside `CCClippingNode`, writing into the depth buffer is disabled using `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`, but the depth test is still enabled. Since the depth buffer is never cleared, I suspect that the depth test is failing, resulting in the stencil never being drawn.

In addition, the `CCGLView` must be created with `depthFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES` in order for `CCClippingNode` to use stencils in the first place.

Comment: This worked perfectly. We only needed to set the depth property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't setup my CCGLView correctly. I have to setup the depth format    to GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES instead of the value 0

set the depthFormat in AppController.mm

[image]